# Wordpress perpetually loads when trying to publish a new post

Tags: database, wordpress

I recently delivered a new Wordpress website for a client. He has issues with creating new posts (in a custom post type). Whenever he tries to create a new one and clicks the publish/update button, it just perpetually loads. Then sometimes the post gets created, but with no title or content. I can't reproduce this issue on my side because it just works when I do it. We both use Safari.

He also told me that when he did not enter a title, it worked. Then added a title to the post, tried to update and it was hanging again. Then when he opens the editor in a new tab and adds the title again, it does work and the change goes through. I also checked the host's error logs and there is nothing there. I contacted the host and they also couldn't find anything.

Does anyone have experience with what is going on here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first step of troubleshooting this kind of confusing stuff is to look at the browser console log in the browser that's experiencing the errors. Are there any error messages? The second step is to look at the Network tab of the browser's devtools, again in the browser experiencing errors. Are any requests failing? This kind of thing can happens if something blocks Gutenberg's AJAX-style requests to the WordPress site. Simple workaround: use the classic editor.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We are working remotely so I don't have access to the computer/browser experiencing these issues. I'll try to explain to him how to check the console. We are currently using the classic editor + ACF. He also just informed me that he turned off his VPN and after that it worked as expected. Could this have been the issue?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, his VPN could be blocking, or slowing down, AJAX requests between his browser and the site you set up for him.  If it's a corporate VPN, your customer should tell his IT staff about the problem and ask them to make sure your site is accessible. My "look at the console" advice allows people to observe these problems as they happen.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved the issue.